# Python string operation, extract text between html tags

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I have a string:

```
<font face="ARIAL,HELVETICA" size="-2">  
JUL 28         </font>
```

(it outputs over two lines, so there must be a \n in there.

I wish to extract the string that's in between the `<font></font>` tags. In this case, it's JUL 28, but it might be another date or some other number.

1) The best way to extract the value from between the font tags? I was thinking I could extract everything in between `">` and `</`.

edit: second question removed.

Comment: Note, the <font face="........> tag is not ALWAYS the same.

Comment: This should probably be two separate questions..

Comment: You're probably right. Let's ignore the second one. I'll worry about that later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it may be possible to parse arbitrary HTML with regular expressions, it's often a death trap. There are great tools out there for parsing HTML, including [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which is a Python lib that can handle *broken* as well as good HTML fairly well.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
>>> BS = BSHTML("""
... <font face="ARIAL,HELVETICA" size="-2">  
... JUL 28         </font>"""
... )
>>> BS.font.contents[0].strip()
u'JUL 28'
```

Then you just need to parse the date:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(BS.font.contents[0].strip(), '%b %d')
>>> datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 28, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 28, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Nice! This seems much less complicated than the regex way.

Comment: @FluxCapacitor A word of warning: My second argument to `strptime` above is actually a locale-specific example. Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more details if you need a locale-agnostic or different locale solution.

Answer (score 6):

You have a bunch of options here. You could go for an all-out xml parser like lxml, though you seem to want a domain-specific solution. I'd go with a multiline regex:

```
import re
rex = re.compile(r'<font.*?>(.*?)</font>',re.S|re.M)
...
data = """<font face="ARIAL,HELVETICA" size="-2">  
JUL 28         </font>"""

match = rex.match(data)
if match:
    text = match.groups()[0].strip()
```

Now that you have `text`, you can turn it into a date pretty easily:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime(text, "%b %d")
```

Comment: You commented on AnthonyHurst's answer that this is from a website. I've used lxml's html parsing with a lot of success recently, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen something similar with regular expressions in another question, but wasn't able to make it work. Your solution worked for me perfectly. The downside is that I only sort of understand what's going on with it.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a library called [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). Also see the following question posted in SO which is very similar to what you are looking for:

[How can I use the python HTMLParser library to extract data from a specific div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div)

Comment: Broken link. It should be https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html or https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser

Comment: Fixed the link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could simply use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python HTML/XML parser designed for quick turnaround projects like screen-scraping

Comment: Probably overkill but a good choice if there's more HTML parsing to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Is grep an option?

```
grep "<[^>]*>(.*)<\/[^>]*>" file
```

The (.*) should match your content.

Comment: I'm doing all this in Python... I used scrapy to scrape a webpage and drill down to arrive at the string above.

Comment: sorry then I couldn't assist you better.  you could always use the re (regular expression) library to grab the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scrapy's XPath selectors as documented at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/selectors.html

Alternatively you can utilize an HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup especially if want to operate on the document in an object oriented manner.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.0