# Get a substring within two strings

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, truncate

I have a very very big string that containing a log from a certain system
I want only the part that starts with `<status>` and ends with `</status>`.
I heard that RegEx expression is a good way, but I don't really know how to use it.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to so with the text in status?

Comment: @sarcoma i want to print a random line inside it for personal use

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911504/python-string-operation-extract-text-between-html-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "Hello I am a very long string <status>I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts</status> here they are standing in a row"
excerpt = s.partition("<status>")[2].rpartition("</status>")[0]
print excerpt
```

Result:

```
I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts
```

Comment: This won't quite work correctly if there are multiple sections with `<status>....</status>` but this is definitely the most efficient way to accomplish this task (assuming the whole text is loaded into memory)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try regex, here's a way:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\<status\>(.*?)\</status\>", re.IGNORECASE)
s = """This is some long random text <status>This is the first status block</status> 
and some more text <status>and another block</status> 
and yet more <status>This is the last status block</status>"""
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

yields

```
['This is the first status block', 'and another block', 'This is the last status block']
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cQ6yW2/1)

The key advantage of this method is that it extracts *all* `<status>...</status>` blocks on a line, not just the first one. Note that for triple-quoted strings, both `<status>` and `</status>` need to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one occurrence of the `<status>` and `</status>`, then you can use `string_name[string_name.index("<status>") + 8: string_name.index("</status>"]`.

```
s = "test<status>test2</status>"
print s[s.index("<status>") + 8: s.index("</status>"]
```

Output:

```
test2
```