# How to extract text from between html tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a some `html` elements from which I want to extract the text. So the `html` is like

```
<pre>
<span class="ansi-red-fg">ZeroDivisionError</span>Traceback (most recent call last)
<span class="ansi-green-fg">&lt;ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc&gt;</span> in <span class="ansi-cyan-fg">&lt;module&gt;</span><span class="ansi-blue-fg">()</span>

</pre>
```

where I want to extract the text as

```
ZeroDivisionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc> in<module>()
```

I found an answer to that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911504/python-string-operation-extract-text-between-html-tags), but it does not work for me. Complete example code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML

bs = BSHTML("""<pre>
<span class="ansi-red-fg">ZeroDivisionError</span>Traceback (most recent call last)
<span class="ansi-green-fg">&lt;ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc&gt;</span> in <span class="ansi-cyan-fg">&lt;module&gt;</span><span class="ansi-blue-fg">()</span>
</pre>""")
print bs.font.contents[0].strip()
```

where I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invest.py", line 13, in <module>
    print bs.font.contents[0].strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

Anything I am missing? Version of `beautifulsoap`: 4.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want all the text content of that `pre` block?

```
print bs.pre.text
```

Returns:

```
ZeroDivisionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc> in <module>()
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks

Comment: But it is not a general solution of getting EVERY text, no matter what tags I have...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I would not have the `pre` tags your approach would not work. I do not care about the tag, I just want the enclosed text. If they are enclosed in `pre`, in `font` or whatever. I do not care about what tags are around. I just want the enclosed text...

Comment: Then just do `bs.text`

Answer (score 0):

The `.font` in your code sample refers to the HTML tag `<font>`. Since you are instead looking to all the text from your document, you can use something like this:

```
contents = bs.find_all(text=True)
for c in contents:
    print(c)  # replace this with whatever you're trying to do
```

Output:

```
ZeroDivisionError
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc>
 in
<module>
()
```

Currently `bs.font` is `None` because you are parsing a document that doesn't contain any `<font>` tags.

If you just want the contents as one long string, you can get that by just using `bs.text`

```
'\nZeroDivisionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)\n<ipython-input-2-0f9f90da76dc> in <module>()\n'
```

Comment: Does not quite work. I do not get the phrase `Traceback (most recent call last)`...

Comment: Also, it does not preserve new lines!

Comment: Ah, I see I misinterpreted your document. Edited to grab everything (and also retain newlines).