# error 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror

I am trying to take line 75 from a webpage and then print the important part in the middle of the line out by splitting the html things (using urllib.request)

```
sourcecode=r.readlines()
baa=sourcecode[74]
codebaa=str(baa.split('<var>','</var>')[1])
print(str(codebaa))
```

I get the error below and I don't understand why at all.

```
  codebaa=str(baa.split('<var>','</var>')[1])
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: The optional second parameter to `str.split()` is a number specifying the maximum number of splits to be done. What were you expecting a second string to do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading up on [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split). The error is due to you passing a string as the second argument to the split function. It's expecting an integer as the `maxsplit`. Since you're trying to parse HTML, I think you should avoid doing that completely and use a parser as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911504/python-string-operation-extract-text-between-html-tags).