# HTMLParser - only extract img tag

Tags: python, html

I am using HTMLParser to extract an image url from a simple html text like this:

```
html = <p><span style="font-size: 17px;"><span style="color: #993300;"><img style="margin-right: 15px; vertical-align: top;" src="images/announcements.png" alt="announcements" /><cite>some message I would like to preserve with its formatting</cite></span></span></p>
```

Now I also need a version of the above html without the img tag, but am having difficulty with closing tags in the right spot. Here is what I tried:

```
class MyHtmlParser(HTMLParser):
    '''
    Parse simple url to extract data and image url.
    This is expecting a simple url containing only one data block and one iimage url.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.noImgHtml = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'img':
            for a in attrs:
                if a[0] == 'src':
                    self.imageUrl = a[1]
        else:
            print '<%s>' % tag
            self.noImgHtml += '<%s>' % tag
            for a in attrs:
                print '%s=%s' % a
                self.noImgHtml += '%s=%s' % a

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.noImgHtml += '</%s>' % tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.noImgHtml += data
```

The output of MyHtmlParser().feed(html) is this:

```
<b>LATEST NEWS:</b><p><span>style=font-size: 17px;<span>style=color: #993300;</img><cite>The image uploader works again, so make sure to use some screenshots in your uploads/tutorials to make your submission look extra nice</cite></span></span></p>
```

As you can see (and as is expected from my code flow), the tags aren't closed the way they were in the original html (e.g. span>).

can this be done easily with HTMLParser or should I resort to RE to extract the image tag (which doesn't seem very elegant)?

I can't use external modules to do this so need to make do with what HTMLParser has to offer.

Thanks in advance,
frank

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code is working, you may use

```
parser = MyHtmlParser()
parser.feed(html)
parser.noImgHtml
```

is really what you want. I tried it, the output is

```
<p><span>style=font-size: 17px;<span>style=color: #993300;</img><cite>some message I would like to preserve with its formatting</cite></span></span></p>
```

except that you need to change the `handle_endtag` function to

```
def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag ！= 'img'
        self.noImgHtml += '</%s>' % tag
```

to exclude the endtag of `img`.

In fact `MyHtmlParser().feed(html)` only `print` the result, it returns nothing. The reason 
the tags are not closed properly in the printed output is you did not `print` the `endtag` and the content of the tag in `handle_endtag` and `handle_data`.

If you are trying to deal with nested divs, Alex answer here maybe helpful.
[How can I use the python HTMLParser library to extract data from a specific div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div?rq=1)
.

Comment: thanks, but this would still not leave the tags with attributes formatted properly, right? I just stumbled over HTMLParser.get_starttag_text() which seems to be what I need to reconstruct the original html

Comment: I see the problem here, you may also tweak the `handle_starttag` method, in the `else` part, add `<tag` first, then the attrs, then the closing `>`.

Comment: But obvious `get_starttag_text` should be used since we don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLParser.get_starttag_text() seems to be the ticket to reconstruct the original html. This seems to work:

```
class MyHtmlParser(HTMLParser):
    '''
    Parse simple url to extract data and image url.
    This is expecting a simple url containing only one data block and one iimage url.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.noImgHtml = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'img':
            for a in attrs:
                if a[0] == 'src':
                    self.imageUrl = a[1]
        else:
            self.noImgHtml += self.get_starttag_text()


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag != 'img':
            self.noImgHtml += '</%s>' % tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.noImgHtml += data
        self.text = data
```