# Get return value from HTMLParser class to main class

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, href

Here my current code:

HTMLParser class:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == "href":
                    print value
```

Main class:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
MyHTMLParser().feed(html)
```

TODO:
Any idea to make "value" can be return to main class?
Thank for advance.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3276119/89391) help?

Comment: it's not really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store information you want to collect on your parser instance:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
         HTMLParser.__init__()
         self.links = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a" and 'href' in attrs:
            self.links.append(attrs['href'])
```

then after you have fed HTML into the parser you can retrieve the `links` attribute from the instance

```
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(html)
print parser.links
```

For parsing HTML, I can heartily recommend you look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Comment: can't use BeautifulSoup because I'm using python 2.7 version

Comment: @azmilhafiz: BeautifulSoup is an add-on that works on Python 2 and Python 3, including Python 2.7.