# return data from HTMLParser handle_starttag

Tags: python, html, class, parsing

[My question is a simpler version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div)

I have a youtube iframe:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fY9UhIxitYM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I'm working on a small web app and need to extract the random code (fY9UhIxitYM in this case). I want to use the standard library rather than importing Beautiful Soup.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class YoutubeLinkParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.data = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        data = attrs[2][1].split('/')[-1]
        self.data.append(data)

iframe = open('iframe.html').read()
parser = YoutubeLinkParser()
linkCode = parser.feed(iframe)
```

The examples I have found use handle_data(self, data), but I need information on an attr of the open tag. I can print the value in the method, but when I try to get a return value, linkCode returns 'none'.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`feed()` method doesn't return anything - which is why you are getting `None`. Instead, read the value of `data` property after calling `feed()`:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class YoutubeLinkParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.data = attrs[2][1].split('/')[-1]

iframe = open('iframe.html').read()
parser = YoutubeLinkParser()
parser.feed(iframe)
print parser.data
```

Prints:

```
fY9UhIxitYM
```

Comment: I knew I was starting at the solution unable to see it. Thanks so much!