# Reading a page and parsing it with minidom.parse or minidom.parseString in Python?

Tags: python

I have either of these codes:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
res = urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/webhp#q=apple&start=10')
dom = minidom.parse(res)
```

which gives me the error `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0`

Or this:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
res = urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/webhp#q=apple&start=10')
dom = minidom.parseString(res.read())
```

which gives me the same error. `res.read()` reads fine and is a string.

I would like to parse through the code later. How can I do this using `xml.dom.minidom`?

Comment: Is using `xml.dom.minidom` a requirement, or you are open to using other modules? Believe me, you should make a switch :)

Comment: The documentation for `xml.dom.minidom` does everything I need to do. I prefer to use the standard libraries unless it's really necessary to do otherwise. I saw a bunch of recommendations for `BeautifulSoup`, but I have no use for it if `xml.dom.minidom` works fine.

Comment: To parse web pages, you should use a HTML parser rather than an XML parser.

Comment: @pts Good suggestion, I will try `HTMLParser`

Comment: @JVE999 there are a lot of `BeautifulSoup` recommendations just because it really makes html-parsing easy and intuitive. It would save you time and make web-scraping fun.

Comment: @JVE999: You really should use `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that the page isn't valid XML. It's HTML 5. The `doctype` right at the top tells you this, even if you ignore the content type. You can't parse HTML with an XML parser.*

If you want to stick with what's in the stdlib, you can use [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) (Python 3.x) / [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html) (2.x).** However, you may want to consider third-party libraries like `lxml` (which, despite the name, can parse HTML), `html5lib`, or `BeautifulSoup` (which wraps up a lower-level parser in a really nice interface).

* Well, unless it's XHTML, or the XML output of HTML5, but that's not the case here.

** Do not use `htmllib` unless you're using an old version of Python without a working `HTMLParser`. This module is deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Here's a SO answer describing parsing HTML with `HTMLParser` for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div