# Retrieve information between tags with specific attributes (Python HTMLParser)

Tags: python, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm trying select from HTML page information. I use python and HTMLParse library.

I'd like to get value, that hold inside the next html element:

```
<span class = 'relevant' >Some relevant information <span class = 'param isquery' >Another information </span> etc.</span>
```

I.e. information holds between tag "span", but with specific attribute class = 'relevant'.

Main problem I faced - how can I retrieve information that hold between "span" section, with specific attribute? 
Method handle_endtag(), as I understand have only tag (without any attributes).

An so, I can't use this method if I have nested tags?

P.S. I saw question [How can I use the python HTMLParser library to extract data from a specific div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div), but this question doesn't cover nested tags with specific attribues.

Comment: Try a better html parser like bs4 or lxml. They are much easier to understand.

Comment: Vincent Beltman, thanks a lot!
With using bs4 I've fast solved this problem!