# HTML offline files get content

Tags: python, html, batch-file, html-parsing

I have really much offline html files and I need get from them name, adress etc. And create CSV.

I first try to do it witch batch - example:

```
for /r %%i in (*) DO (
  findstr /o "name" %%i >> results.txt
  ECHO ; >> results.txt

  findstr /o "STREET" %%i >> results.txt
  ECHO ; >> results.txt

  etc

ECHO xxxendlinexxx >> results.txt                                       
)
```

It works, but this give me long file what need hard work with Regular expresion... I think there must be better way how to read TAG content in HTML.

I found Python HTML parser:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

But I dont know hot to use for offline file and specific TAG (id="something"). I googling, watch tuts on youtube, but I dont find easy a understandable solution.

Can you help? Best with example:

1. How open file
2. How find content in specific tag
3. Save content to another file

Thank you for help.

Comment: If you don't provide an example html file with the required data and an example of what you want your csv to look like, how do you expect us to create a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use html.parser, take an example, you want create a parse who get all main title (h1):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    my_titles = []
    target_id = ['article-1-b', 'article-2-a']
    COPY_DATA = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
       if tag == 'h1':
           if 'id' in attrs and attrs['id'] in target_id:
               self.COPY_DATA = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.COPY_DATA:
            self.my_titles.append(data)
            self.COPY_DATA = False


parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open('my_file.html') as f:
    parser.feed(f.read())

print(parser.my_titles)
```

Comment: Thank you, this help.

But i have a litte more question - I can add more tags - like H2 etc. But in some cases i must use "id" or "class" etc. for finding the right tag, I found some code here on stacoverflow - it works, bud im not able to combinate that together in one function. Did you understand? There is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div

Comment: I don't sure to understand but I have edited code. Look and tell me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use module `xml` instead of `html.parser` to work with xml or html. It is easier.

I use module `xml.etree` but there are others (doc: [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html))

You can read from file (`ET.parse(filename)`) but in example I use string.

You have to learn how to use `xpath` (ie. `'.//div[@id="something"]'`) to find elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html_string = '''<html>
<body>
<div id="something">Hello</div>
<div id="something">World</div>
</body>
</html>'''

#tree = ET.parse(filename)
tree = ET.fromstring(html_string)

divs = tree.findall('.//div[@id="something"]')

# --- screen ---

for d in divs:
    print(d.text)

# --- file ---

with open('output.txt') as f:
    for d in divs:
        f.write(d.text + '\n')
```